# How to display 4 div elements next to each other while position: fixed?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make 4 boxes fixed in the bottom middle of the page.
But When I apply `position: Fixed;` to them, they just become one stacked box.

```css
.g{
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="groups">
  <div class="g g1"></div>
  <div class="g g2"></div>
  <div class="g g3"></div>
  <div class="g g4"></div>
</div>
```

What I want is this:
[image]

Comment: make the container to be fixed instead

Comment: Yours didn't work because '15%' only works if the parent container has height set.. but yes, the answers you are getting provide a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make outer div `fixed` then inner 4 div element will show next to each other.

```css
      .groups {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    justify-content: space-around;
    max-width: 500px;
}
      .g{
        height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 5px;
      }
```

```html
      <div class="groups">
          <div class="g g1"></div>
          <div class="g g2"></div>
          <div class="g g3"></div>
          <div class="g g4"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can do it with flex:

```css
.g{
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
}
.groups {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 400px
}
```

```html
<div class="groups">
  <div class="g g1"></div>
  <div class="g g2"></div>
  <div class="g g3"></div>
  <div class="g g4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/c1kjmsxv/)

```
.groups{
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 15%;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 width:100%;
 }
.g{
 height: 70px;
 width: 70px;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 5px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float:left;` to the css class .g
Of course you MUST remove `position: fixed;`
You can also use `position: fixed;` but you must provide different values for position for each div.

```
<div class="groups">
  <div class="g g1"></div>
  <div class="g g2"></div>
  <div class="g g3"></div>
  <div class="g g4"></div>
</div>

<div class="groups">
  <div class="h h1"></div>
  <div class="h h2"></div>
  <div class="h h3"></div>
  <div class="h h4"></div>
</div>

.g {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  float:left; /* add this */
  border: 1px solid red;  
  bottom: 15%; 
}

.h {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  position:fixed;
}

.h1 {
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 20px;
}

.h2 {
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 100px;
}

.h3 {
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 180px;
}

.h4 {
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 260px;
}
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/d4rvy0Lc/)

Comment: @MareGraphics MaRe: The Fiddle link is now working. Sorry, I don't know how it happend: I provided a not working one.

Comment: @MareGraphics MaRe: aren't you satisfied with my answer? Have you looked at the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

As position is fixed, you may need to sepcify the positions of class g1, g2 and g3 like below.

```
.g1{
    left: 0px;
}
.g2{
    left: 100px;
}
.g3{
    left: 200px;
}
```